# strpos is not matching

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

I want search one string and get related values, but in test the function, in each times search words(`Title` Or `Would` Or `Post` Or `Ask`) displaying(give) just one output `Title,11,11` !!!! how can fix it?

```
  // test array
  $arr = array('Title,11,11','Would,22,22','Post,55,55','Ask,66,66');
  // define search function that you pass an array and a search string to
  function search($needle,$haystack){
    //loop over each passed in array element
    foreach($haystack as $v){
      // if there is a match at the first position
      if(strpos($needle,$v) == 0)
        // return the current array element
        return $v;
    }
    // otherwise retur false if not found
    return false;
  }
  // test the function
  echo search("Would",$arr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in `strpos`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php 
The haystack is the first argument and the second argument is the needle. 
You should also do a `===` comparison for getting 0.

```
// test array
$arr = array('Title,11,11','Would,22,22','Post,55,55','Ask,66,66');
// define search function that you pass an array and a search string to
function search($needle,$haystack){
  //loop over each passed in array element
  foreach($haystack as $v){
    // if there is a match at the first position
    if(strpos($v,$needle) === 0)
      // return the current array element
      return $v;
  }
  // otherwise retur false if not found
  return false;
}
// test the function
echo search("Would",$arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Source: http://php.net/strpos

Answer (score 0):

change this check:

```
// if there is a match at the first position
if(strpos($needle,$v) == 0)
  // return the current array element
  return $v;
```

to

```
// if there is a match at the first position
if(strpos($needle,$v) === 0)
  return $v;
```

or

```
// if there is a match anywhere
if(strpos($needle,$v) !== false)
  return $v;
```

[strpos returns false](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues) if the string isn't found, but checking for `false == 0` gives true, because php treats `0` as `false`. to prevent this, you'll have to use the `===` operator (or `!==`, depending on what exactly you're trying to do).