# strpos is not finding needle

Tags: php, strpos

I have a form that posts some html to a php file i have split each line into an array and am looping through the array but anything i try and to to search,reaplace etc on ">" just returns nothing

here is the php im using

```
$catsLines = explode("\n", $cats);

    foreach($catsLines as $cat){

        print strpos(">",$cat);
    }
```

Here is a sample of the html:

```
<option value="283">35mm &amp; 120 Copy Pages, Glassine Backed Pages, Glassine Pages - 35mm-120-copy-pages-glassine-backed-pages-glassine-pages.html</option>
<option value="266">Black Card Masks - pc7.html</option>
<option value="284">Clear Faced Bags &amp; Resealable Bags - pc12.html</option>
```

Any help is much apreciated been stuck on this ages

Lewis

Comment: replace `strpos(">",$cat)` with `strpos($cat, ">")`. params are switched

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466998/problem-in-function-strpos?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos(">",$cat)` should be `strpos($cat, ">")` the params are switched.

[Documentation](http://php.net/strpos)